# Integral inequality, Hölder-type, any idea?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, inequality, integral-inequality

Is it possible for a number $\alpha>1$ to have such a kind of inequality?
$$\int_A f^{-\alpha} \leq C \left( \int_A f\right)^{-\alpha},$$
where the measure of $A$ is finite $A$ and $f\geq 0$ is a positive function.

If not, is there any kind of inequality one could exploit for $\int_A f^{-\alpha}$ in roder to get rid of the exponent $-\alpha$ inside the integral?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don' think that such an estimate exists. As an example, choose
$f(x) = 2x$ on $A = (0, 1)$. Then the right-hand side is $C$ whereas the left-hand side is $\infty$ for every $\alpha > 1$.